# debian multi-arch, android sdk

Tags: debian, 64-bit, android, debian-wheezy

I didn't know about the multi-arch big change on debian 7 wheezy, i'd have stuck with i386 install if I knew since I have no need for what amd64 brings to the table...

but it is too late, i have a amd64 install, and now wants to run android's adb

```
host$ file platform-tools/adb 
platform-tools/adb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped

host$ platform-tools/adb 
bash: platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
```

my first reaction was, simple 32 bit in a 64 bit env (why the hell google jokes with our minds by providing a download for linux32 and linux64 if both will be a dammed 32bit?) ... so i tried to install ia32-libs just to find out debian7 does not have them anymore and that I am supposed to use multi-arch.

I read the https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO and added another foreign-arch... but what now? the how-to has no mention about what to do after that. how do i even find out what that binary is trying to load? will I have to debug every 32bit binary i have to run?

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
aptitude update
aptitude install libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Can you please also explain what the code does?

Comment: @slhck it installs the most commons libraries, exactly what i was afraid. So instead of the ia32lib hack, now debian/ubuntu ships every library to bot archs. which is probably much cleaner, but we are back to dependency hell if not using a properly package binary. also the debian howto lacks that _little_ detail. more info here http://askubuntu.com/a/394156/16461

Answer (score 0):

It seems ia32-libs is deprecated. Try this instead. Worked for me in Crunchbang.

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

Comment: And what do you do after that? I already did that after reading the how-to, but as far as I understood, that only gives me the ability to download the i386 libs that I know I need. Do I have to run `ldd` on each binary, find the debian package that provides each lib shown, and install? the ia-32 thing was very convenient...

Comment: btw, this is exactly what i mentioned I already did on the penultimate paragraph (the one i mention the HOW TO link)... but no idea how go on after that.